# Fission of U-235 produces Cs-137 along with...?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radiation, neutrons

Question about Nuclear fission in general, here. If I have the fission of U-235 and I know that one of the products is Cs-137, is there a way of figuring out the other product? Should there be multiple possibilities? I understand that total number of Nucleons is preserved, but I'm supposing that I need to take into account that neutrons alone are also released? 
I'm almost certain that if I can work out the other product then I won't be able to know the isotope that it is, but can I even work out the atomic number of the other element? If so, how?

Many thanks

Comment: Note that the direct fission yield of Cs-137 from thermal fission of U-235 is relatively low. The cumulative yield of Cs-137 is mainly due to the fission products Xe-137, I-137, and Te-137, which decay to Cs-137.

Comment: Do you have a source for that information which I could also use? Or is that just your own knowledge? I've been looking for a place which would just display common fission products for various isotopes but have come up dry so far.

Comment: Fission product yields are available from various databases, for example [here](http://wwwndc.jaea.go.jp/cgi-bin/nuclinfo2014?55,137). You may want to compare the cumulative fission yield of Cs-137 (6.2 %) with the independent fission yield of Cs-137 (0.06 %).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fission reaction produce a distribution of several different nuclei. Wikipedia (User:JWB) has a [nice graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission_product#/media/File:ThermalFissionYield.svg) that shows the relative probabilities.

However, in the case of a single reaction, where it is ***given*** that a Cs-137 nucleus is produced, you can probably be more specific because there are correlations between the fission products, but it will require delving into the nuclear data - https://www-nds.iaea.org/

Comment: I would say that this answer is better than mine, so it's better to rely upon it

Comment: Good answer. And with a useful link too! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[As indicated in the answer to this physics.stackexchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201713/fission-producing-cs-137) the total amount of nucleons is preserved during fission.

As a result the atomic number of a daughter product can be predicted if another was already known. In the case of $U_{92}^{235}$ fissioning to $Cs_{55}^{137}$, we know the atomic number of the second fission product is given by:

$92=55+Z$, i.e. $Z=37$, which is the atomic nummber of Rb (rubidium).

Now as to the atomic weight of the Rb isotope, also use preservation of neutrons.

A $U_{92}^{235}$ nucleus contains $235-92=143$ neutrons and a $Cs_{55}^{137}$ nucleus contains $137-55=82$ neutrons. The difference is $143-82=61$ neutrons to be allocated.

Assume that $2$ to $4$ free neutrons also resulted from the fission then that leaves $57$ to $59$ neutrons for the Rb isotope so **its atomic weight is probably $94$ to $98$.**

Answer (score 0):

Actually fission processes are stochastic, so we can't predict exact products of it. The most probable fission products are Cs-137 and Sr-90. The total amount of neutrons emitted is also quite unpredictable, but as I recall it usually lies in the range between 2 and 4.